# Making a career in CS vs Software engineer

Tags: software-engineering

this might be a bit philosophical question , but i haven't really gotten a good answer. 
Theoretical computer science vs Software engineer / developer whatever, which one is better for making good money.

I love maths and theoretical computer science. I am very ambitious, slightly arrogant guy from Estonia. I am first yeah Bachelor student, but I don't know where to go from here. I study a lot and i want to be successful and the best at what i do, so all tips are welcome if you think of something that could help me.
I think 95 % or more of my coursemates don't like maths, they just like programming. I minor in mathematics also , i understand it well and i am the best out of 160 persons in maths. I have done some projects in CS and it is okay, i kind of like it,but i feel like it's not my calling.

I also always look for business oppurtunities, have failed 2 or 3 projects due to funding and other reasons, i won't go into that right now.

My second question is : What CS field i should focus on ? Right now i am thinking of parallel computing, computational neuroscience, artificial intelligence and cryptography. I think these are the fields where i might make some money.

If people ask me where do i see myself in 10-20 years, i usually say that i will be my own employer or something. I understand maths very well and i study it a lot. I also study electrical engineering, chemistry , physics at introductionary level, for fun :). (From coursera, mit open courseware and so on ... ).

My third question is : What I should study to make something innovative in the future, that is high end ? ( this is why I study physics and electrical engineering )

Fourth : Is there a theoretical CS field that I could make my own start-up on ?

Sorry for bad English , I'm learning it also right now :)

Comment: It sounds like you should read http://www.paulgraham.com/wealth.html but I'm voting to close.

Comment: You want life advice, not help with computer science; this is nothing we can do here. You might be able to get some opinions in [chat].

Comment: a decent/relevant question in the title but not in the contents....